# Google Maps Javascript API Billing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to use any of these 3 APIs:

1. Maps JavaScript API
2. Geocoding API
3. StreetViewPanorama(Dynamic Street
   View)

But I could not get an exact information on how the billing works. 
I want to know 2 things regarding these:

1. By using any of these APIs, can we get requests for free without adding the billing details?
2. If its mandatory to add billing details, how many requests will I get for free if billing details are added?

Anyone who knows these, please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the use of a third-party service and not about programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> By using any of these APIs, can we get requests for free without adding the billing details?

No, you will have to add the billing details to get the requests.

> If its mandatory to add billing details, how many requests will I get for free if billing details are added?

You get the equivalent of 200$ per month for free. The price of each request is stated here: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/.

Once you have used 200$ worth of requests, you will have to start paying.

If you are afraid of going beyond the free 200$ per month you can setup quotas to prevent sudden, unexpected bills.

For example: "if i have to spend more than 1$, stop serving the APIs." so that your bill at the end of the month will be maximum 1$ - or 0$ if you so please:

> Manage Your Cost of Use
>
> To manage your cost of use of the Google Maps Platform APIs, you can set daily limits to all requests to any billable API.
>
> To view or change daily billable limits for the Maps JavaScript API, do the following:
>
> Go to the Maps JavaScript API Quotas page in the Google Cloud Platform Console.
>
> From the projects list, select a project. In the Requests section, on the Requests per day line, click the edit icon, then enter the preferred total billable daily quota, up to the limit (if any) specified by Google.

From: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing#set-caps

Comment: If you are creating a brand new account, you will be eligible for an additional $300 free credit as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use maps services, you will need to provide a valid billing account/payment method. this is because once your free trial period is over or free trial credit is fully used up then you can simply upgrade to a paid account.

Once you have a valid/working billing account then you are entitled to receive a free $200/month maps credits. once this credits is fully consumed then it checks for your free trial credit worth $300 valid for 1 year. if you have this free trial credits then it can be use to offset any charges. otherwise if your account does not have a free trial credits left then you will get billed automatically using the payment method setup on your account.